# How is spectral clustering related to bayesian clustering methods?

Tags: graph-theory, bayesian, spectral-graph-theory, clustering

What is the advantage of spectral clustering over bayesian cluster estimation techniques like stochastic block models, mixed-membership stochastic block models?

Comment: "Bayesian clustering methods" includes a really wide range of clustering algorithms. Are you specifically asking about stochastic block models?

Comment: @jtb I am talking in general.  What kind of assumption spectral clustering makes? Does it have a relationship with any of the Bayesian community detection methods?